# REST API авторизация через социальные сети

Tags: auth, oauth2, rest

Есть бекенд REST API на Node JS и работает авторизация через логин/пароль с помощью OAuth 2.

Стал вопрос о том чтобы добавить авторизацию через социальные сети (Facebook, Twitter, Google +).

Но я не до конца понимаю как это должно работать правильно.

В голове такой вариант работы:

1. мобильное приложение (или другой клиент) получает токен от соц. сети и шлет его на бекенд, скажем по пути /auth/facebook
2. сервер принимает данные, обращается к facebook с помощью токена, получает модель пользователя сверяет по ID в БД на предмет уже имеющегося пользователя и сохраняет в БД если такой отсутствует.

Далее генерирует локальные OAuth токены (Access, Refresh) и отправляет пользователю.

**Вопрос:** подскажите пожалуйста, это правильный подход?

Answer (score 0):

Тоже задался таким вопросом но для Angular 2 приложения которое существует на неком домене mydomain.com.

Как я себе представляю, то приложение должно обратиться за разрешением к сервису (аля Facebook), Facebook редиректит на страницу maydomain.com/facebook, Приложение получает от Facebook code и пересылает его бэкенду, и уже бэкенд договаривается с Facebook и получает access_token по этому коду. При помощи acess_token обращается к api и получает информацию о id, email, user_name, генерирует из id foto_url. Создает профиль пользователя и далее при запросах к бэкенду он уже должен проверять access_token. Может я и не прав, но пока точной информации не нашел.

Если Вы уже накопали рабочее решение, то известите плиз!

Comment: Для клиентских приложений лучше использовать implicit-flow получения токена. Тогда вам не нужно будет гонять code на бэк (тем более так его можно перехватить)